# How do I prevent line.replace from removing extra lines?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to eliminate a line in a file, but when I do a line.replace function, it replaces things that shouldn't be replaced.

I tried line.replace to remove the "SCOPE1EXPRESSION" line, but it removed additional lines that I want to keep.

The input file looks like this:

```
SCOPE1EXPRESSION
InDifferentialPairClass'DIFF100'
TOPLAYER_PREFGAP
6.2992mil
BOTTOMLAYER_PREFGAP
6.2992mil
SCOPE1EXPRESSION
InDifferentialPairClass'DIFF90'
TOPLAYER_PREFGAP
4.4882mil
BOTTOMLAYER_PREFGAP
4.4882mil
```

Then I try line.replace("SCOPE1EXPRESSION","") to remove it:

```
'''
infile = open(('All_Rules1.txt'),'r')
outfile = open('All_Rules2.txt','w+')
for line in infile:
    line = line.replace("SCOPE1EXPRESSION","")
    if pattern.search(line):
        outfile.write(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
sys.stdout.flush()
'''
```

and the result is:

```
InDifferentialPairClass'DIFF100'
TOPLAYER_PREFGAP
BOTTOMLAYER_PREFGAP
InDifferentialPairClass'DIFF90'
TOPLAYER_PREFGAP
BOTTOMLAYER_PREFGAP
```

How can I prevent it from removing extra lines?

I expected *only* the "SCOPE1EXPRESSION" to be removed.

Comment: I don't think it's replacing it, I think that the extra lines being removed don't pass the `if pattern.search(line)` test and aren't written to the outfile.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I used the pattern.search(line) feature to create the first file (from a very large file) but didn't remove it when doing the fine adjustments. Thanks!

Comment: Carter, also when I have multiple lines that have the same word but an incremented number, such as test1, test2, test3... is there a way to replace all lines (entirely) that have "test" in it? I tried test* but that didn't work.

Comment: Check out [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)